# if in pandas data frame : TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, typeerror, nonetype

I am lost in some simple pandas op.

I am getting the error:
**TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'**

When evauating the following statement:

```
self.df.sma_s.iloc[-1] < self.df.sma_l.iloc[-1]
```

The weird thing is that my dataframe actually contains floats in those fiels.

Trying to debug, I did the following:

```
    self.df['sma_s'] = self.df.close.rolling(sma_s).mean()
    self.df['sma_l'] = self.df.close.rolling(sma_l).mean()

    self.current_position = self.check_positions()

    print('gonna check for trades')

    print(self.df.sma_s.iloc[-1])
    print(type(self.df.sma_s.iloc[-1]))

    print(self.df.sma_l.iloc[-1])
    print(type(self.df.sma_l.iloc[-1]))

    print('='*50)
    print(self.df.tail(5))

    over = self.df.sma_s.iloc[-1] > self.df.sma_l.iloc[-1]
    print(f'Over: {over}')

    under = self.df.sma_s.iloc[-1] < self.df.sma_l.iloc[-1]
    print(f'Under: {under}')

    if over and np.sign(self.current_position) != 1:
        self.close_position()
        trade = self.buy(self.qty)
        
    elif under and np.sign(self.current_position) != -1:
        self.close_position()
        trade = self.sell(self.qty)
```

The results are:

```
gonna check for trades
 1.1847966666666665 
<class 'numpy.float64'>
 1.1848311111111112 
<class 'numpy.float64'>
 
  date                      sma_s     sma_l   
2021-07-28 16:23:00-04:00  1.184852  1.184856
2021-07-28 16:24:00-04:00  1.184860  1.184863
2021-07-28 16:25:00-04:00  1.184847  1.184853
2021-07-28 16:26:00-04:00  1.184820  1.184837
2021-07-28 16:27:00-04:00  1.184797  1.184831
Over: False 
Under: True
```

But it still gives me the error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
    176 
--> 177         elif under and np.sign(self.current_position) != -1:
    178             self.close_position()
    179             trade = self.sell(self.qty)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

**How come, when I ask it to print,self.df.sma_s.iloc[-1] is a *float64* and self.df.sma_s.iloc[-1] > self.df.sma_l.iloc[-1] it is a *boolean*, but when I evaluate it inside the "*if*" I get that error?**
It does not make any sense to me!
any clues?

Thanks!!

Comment: What is the value of `self.current_position` before your `if/elif` block?

Comment: Thanks! the problem was actually there... I was completly blinded by the "<" on the error message so I though the problem was related to the first condition inside the if... but it actually was a problem of the np.sign()